# Block LU decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Could you give me a hand with finding the LU decomposition of the following matrix :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyza0.jpg)

where B belongs to R nxn and prove that det(A)>0.

I tried in following way:

tried to use the cholesky block decomposition:

L1*L1T = I => L1=L1T=I

L1*L2T=L2T=BT => B = L2

L2*L1T=-B => L2 *I = -B=> -B=L2 (I got stuck here )

To make sure the indication will be correctly read i drawn it in Paint, 
sorry for that, but I don't know how do it in other way.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgpdw.png)

What is wrong with my thinking?

Comment: Imagine they are scalars. What would you do?

Comment: I did in such a way, but I end up with sth like:
B*I=-B and don't know how to proceed

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your formulas. What are L1 and L2? Please use mathjax/Tex.

Comment: Tried to explain, sorry for that...

Comment: You can't use cholesky, as $A$ isn't symmetric in general. You need LU decomposition. You can type formula like $L_1^T$ by `$L_1^T$`.

Comment: Should I use Block LU decomposition which definitione can be found on the Wikipedia.org? Could you give some hint?

Comment: For example. ${}$

Comment: I used LDU decomposition from wikipedia and still don't know what is next step ? have you got any manual how should I proceede?

Comment: As for the determinant, the determinant of a triangular block matrix is the product of the determinants of the diagonal blocks.